# Doing some operations Until Subprocess Check output is completed

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to do some task while subprocess.checkoutput is being completed
for example in the below snippets I am pinging google for 10 second, for these 10 seconds until print statement is trigger instead of staying idle is there a way to print some  random message like print("ping is still running")

```
import subprocess

ping = subprocess.check_output("ping -n 10 www.google.com.", shell=True, 
stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)

while ping:  # need assistance here
   print("ping is still running")

print(ping)
```

Comment: You can use ```threading``` module

Comment: thanks mkrieger but it didn't help me , all info is about Popen process i just need to wait until subprocess.check_output is completed

Comment: Use subprocess.run(). That will, by default, block until the subprocess has completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **subprocess.run()** instead of **subprocess.check_output()** as below:

```
ping = subprocess.run("ping -n 10 www.google.com.", shell=True, 
stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
```

And you need to apply more time instead of 10 seconds, like 100000000.

Comment: thanks bhavin using your inputs & @Sujay suggestion of using threading I was able to get the desired results